# How to subtract inventory and sale using sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Here is the recursive table format:
[image]

Example:

Suppose I have Input stock number is 500 and Quantity(sale quantity) is 5 then remaining stock is 495 , In the next case when i sell some other item in Input stock must be 495 instead of 500 and if quantity is 6 then 489..

how to calculate using sqlserver??
here is the stored procedure:

```
   select i.itemid,i.ItemName,i.EntryDate as 'Purchase Date',i.PurchaseRate as 'Purchase Amount',
 s.SaleDate,isnull(s.TotalPrice,0)as 'SalesAmount',sum(i.quantity)as 'Input Stock',s.Quantity,
 sum(i.quantity)-sum(ISNULL(s.quantity,0)) as 'Remaining Stock'
 from Inv_Medicine i
 left join Inv_Sales s on s.itemid=i.itemid
 group by i.itemid,i.ItemName,i.EntryDate,i.PurchaseRate,s.SaleDate,s.TotalPrice,s.Quantity
```

The above query not working..any suggestion???

How to subtract inventory and sale ??

i want instead of 500 must be 495 and after 495 if quantity is 6 remaining stock 489..depends upon the data(input stock and quantity data dynamically)

here is the Inv_Medicine and Inv_Sale table format and table:
Inv_Medicine:
[image]

Inv_Medicine structure:
[image]

Inv_Sale:
[image]

Inv_Sale structure:
[image]

Comment: hi @Manoj , itemid is duplicate allow or not ?

Comment: Please provide Inv_Medicine  and Inv_Sales  table structure with dummy data .

Comment: yes itemid may be duplicate

Comment: @RonakPatel i have already given the table format you just check and if you need to any modification just suuggest me..

Comment: Here in the inventory system i want to find the total amount of input - total sale..so how much remaining...

Comment: Let me create table in My DB and let me check

Comment: alright..i am waiting for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]manoj ,

```
DECLARE @date1 datetime='2017-01-25 04:48:03.830'
DECLARE @date2 datetime='2017-01-26 04:48:03.830'

 SELECT t1.*, CurrentStock = (isnull(t1.Quantity,0)-
  SUM(isnull(t2.salsesquantity,0)))+isnull(t1.salsesquantity,0),
  isnull(t1.salsesquantity,0)
  as SalesProductQunatity, RemainingStock = isnull(t1.Quantity,0)-
  SUM(isnull(t2.salsesquantity,0)) 

   FROM ( SELECT
  im.ItemName,im.PurchaseRate,Ins.SalesDate,ins.totalprice,ins.quantity
  as salsesquantity,im.Quantity , ROW_NUMBER()OVER( partition by
  Ins.itemId ORDER by ins.SalesDate) as ranknumbr  FROM 
  [dbo].[Inv_Medicine] IM LEFT JOIN [dbo].Inv_Sales Ins on
 IM.ItemId=Ins.ItemId ) t1

  INNER JOIN 
  ( SELECT
  im.ItemName,im.PurchaseRate,Ins.SalesDate,ins.totalprice,ins.quantity
 as salsesquantity,im.Quantity , ROW_NUMBER()OVER( partition by
 Ins.itemId ORDER by ins.SalesDate) as ranknumbr  FROM 
  [dbo].[Inv_Medicine] IM LEFT JOIN [dbo].Inv_Sales Ins on
  IM.ItemId=Ins.ItemId  ) as t2  



 ON t1.ranknumbr >= t2.ranknumbr AND t1.ItemName=t2.ItemName 
 WHERE t1.SalesDate BETWEEN @date1 AND @date2
 GROUP BY
  t1.ranknumbr,
 t1.SalesDate,t1.ItemName,t1.PurchaseRate,t1.totalprice,t1.salsesquantity,
 t1.Quantity,t2.    Quantity

   ORDER by t1.ItemName DESC
```

Please check my answer , It will be help you .
Let me know if you stuck any where .

Comment: sir this query gives the output for only one value(i.e. paracetamol)

Comment: the above code is working very fine for the paracetamol..i want whole the value like my first table image Here is the recursive table format:

Comment: Your image is correct but in my case it will show only paracetamol

Comment: if suppose their is no sale then also this value need to show in the query

Comment: sir in your coflen syrup if sales product quantity is null or zero then also the value need to fetch

Comment: I am using your above query..the query gives the output if sales product quantity is avilable...their is a case when no salesproductquery(null or zero) in this case also i need to fetch all the value

Comment: I am using your above query..except from `enter code here`

Comment: Please check now .

Comment: While i search the date between two sales data "where Ins.SaleDate in between '2017-01-25 05:34:49.283' and '2017-01-25 03:49:12.330'"...where should i write this condition??

Comment: While search between two date or by name where should i change in the above code??

Comment: yes . you just need to between condition before of order by(bottom) .I am on holiday so i am not able to reply you .

Comment: I am using where condition before of order by(bottom)..but it will show me the syntax error..no problem by the way you take rest(holiday)..after return from holiday just inform me..

Comment: yes this query working fine...thanks for your help..bye..have a nice and beautiful day a head..